# Validations using simple_form: validated object lost after hitting create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, validation, simple-form

We have a form created by several controllers's **new** actions, which we reuse via `render :new` in the **create** action to display validation error messages. I believe this is the way to go for simple_form and validations. Correct me, if I'm wrong here.

We also have a general language switching mechanic, that redirects to the current_url, with a different locale.

The problem:
After a failed validation and the second rendering of the new form, the language selection throws an error (which would be very misleading to post here). The problem is that the **create** action expects the validated object, which our language selection does not pass to the current url again.

How would you tackle this problem?

We could try to teach our language switcher about "create" and have it send another post request with the same params, but this seems awful. There would have to be a lot of logic in our little helper and where would we store the objects (at least one kind of them is not persisted at all)?
Someone mentioned (ab-)using a flash message to recreate the object, but it's a huge form with up to 50 validations and this get's uglier with size, I guess.
Storing the object in the session in these cases and have the helper post the object again, if it exists might work. I like this one the most, but it's far from feeling right as well.

We could try to have simple_form use the "new" action instead of just rendering "new", but this seems really bad.

We could disable language switching for **create** actions altogether, with an alert saying this one step has to be finished in the chosen language.

Do you have any opinions, other suggestions? I'd be very grateful.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

So we changed the language helper to send the same post request again, if it is on a page created by a POST. It ended up looking like this. Not a lot of code added:

```
def language_link(language)
  url_options = { locale: language }
  if request.request_method == 'POST'
    link_to(language, url_for(params.merge(url_options)), method: :post)
  else
    link_to(language, url_for(url_options))
  end
end
```

We were carefully making sure we don't end up sending valid data a second time. Creating a second payment, or a second order would be quite bad here for example. We need to keep this in mind in the future as well, when we're creating new post routes accessible on a part of our application where language is changeable. That's the main problem here.

It does not consider PUT requests now because we don't have any edit/update functionality on the part of the app where language is selectable.

We can live with this version in our code. So I post this as an answer. But I'd still be happy to see a better (less dangerous) version, our any thoughts on this at all.

Cheers,
Andy